# Escape string to be valid python expression

Tags: python, python-3.2

My question is simple. Lets assume you have string in python like this `Foo '" \ Bar`.

What is the **correct way** to convert it to *valid python expression* like `'Foo \'" \\ Bar'` (so you just simply can copy&paste it to python interpreter and it'll work)?

I thought of `'"{}"'.format(some replace magic)`, but there's gotta be better solution.

Comment: Instead of replacing stuff or encoding you can also use raw strings with triple quotes: `'r"""%s"""' % your_string`. That should be enough most of the time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`unicode_escape` codec](http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings); this produces a `bytes` instance:

```
>>> example = 'Foo \'" \\ Bar'
>>> print(example)
Foo '" \ Bar
>>> print(example.encode('unicode_escape'))
b'Foo \'" \\\\ Bar'
>>> example.encode('unicode_escape')
b'Foo \'" \\\\ Bar'
```

`unicode_escape` *expliticly* produces valid python string literals:

> Produce a string that is suitable as Unicode literal in Python source code

To go back to Unicode, simply decode from ASCII:

```
>>> print(example.encode('unicode_escape').decode('ascii'))
Foo '" \\ Bar
>>> example.encode('unicode_escape').decode('ascii')
'Foo \'" \\\\ Bar'
```

Alternatively, use [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

```
>>> repr(example)
'\'Foo \\\'" \\\\ Bar\''
>>> print(repr(example))
'Foo \'" \\ Bar'
```

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object. For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`, otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object.

The output of `repr()` of a string can be pasted straight back into a Python interpreter without additional formatting.

Note that `repr()` and `unicode_escape` only escape quotes *when absolutely necessary*. Only when *both* styles of quoting, single and double, are present does one of these get escaped:

```
>>> print(repr('\''))
"'"
>>> print(repr('\"'))
'"'
>>> print(repr('\'"'))
'\'"'
```

Comment: I need to work with the string, not actually print it, so I can't rely on how `print` works.

Comment: @Vyktor: The `prints()` are just there to demonstrate the output. `unicode_escape` produces *valid python literals*.

Comment: Hm, `unicode_escape` doesn't seem to escape `"'`: `print('"\'\\'.encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf-8'))` will result into `"'\\ `. So I'd still need to use `'"' + result.replace('"', '\\"') + '"'` wouldn't I?

Comment: @Vyktor: It doesn't have to. You do not need to escape a single quote inside a double-quoted string.

Comment: The problem is the inner string contains sql with single quotes, double quotes, so it should handle any special character inside. I've added `'"` to question to make that more explicit.

Comment: @Vyktor: I've already updated my answer to demonstrate both methods do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

That’s exactly what `repr` is meant to do:

```
>>> x = '''Foo '" \ Bar'''
>>> repr(x)
'\'Foo \\\'" \\\\ Bar\''
>>> print(repr(x))
'Foo \'" \\ Bar'
```

Comment: Unfortunately Martijn Pieters beat you few seconds to it. But this is right answer :)

Comment: @Vyktor Yeah, he does that a lot ;D